# Get all element with same name from xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I try to get all the "username" element from config.xml using xml.etree.ElementTree.
But cannot get the data using below code, it return None to me.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('config.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
users = tree.findall('username')
print(users)
```

If I use above code to test again some normal xml file, it works.
Here is the config.xml file that I have to use, maybe there is format issue within this file, but I cannot figure out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply
    xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:cf3e02a2-b7bc-475f-a87e-b6571eca99b7"
    xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <data>
        <app-hosting-cfg-data
            xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-app-hosting-cfg">
            <apps>
                <app>
                    <application-name>guestshell</application-name>
                    <application-network-resource>
                        <management-interface-name>0</management-interface-name>
                    </application-network-resource>
                </app>
            </apps>
        </app-hosting-cfg-data>
        <native
            xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
            <version>17.3</version>
            <boot-start-marker/>
            <boot-end-marker/>
            <enable>
                <secret>
                    <type>9</type>
                    <secret>$9$GNcSrWbM1PyCqU$9.BCza34ClqbgyABGzRV1v5hjCWhaoN9K.gqxCtcCvE</secret>
                </secret>
            </enable>
            <username>
                <name>developer</name>
                <privilege>15</privilege>
                <secret>
                    <encryption>9</encryption>
                    <secret>$9$oNguEA9um9vRx.$MsDk0DOy1rzBjKAcySWdNjoKcA7GetG9YNnKOs8S67A</secret>
                </secret>
            </username>
            <username>
                <name>netconf</name>
                <privilege>15</privilege>
                <secret>
                    <encryption>9</encryption>
                    <secret>$9$A7TadNm7VSWsXk$k0eVomchjOb90cjpI5hmLA/n0xlomzUhJ47o5y9WMHc</secret>
                </secret>
            </username>
            <username>
                <name>restconf</name>
                <privilege>15</privilege>
                <secret>
                    <encryption>9</encryption>
                    <secret>$14$eGCL$P15Lf8exJZB3qk$XYVi2eHOhT895Rpx1gYEQcwWfeML3AavoI/lxrMMtD.</secret>
                </secret>
            </username>
            <username>
                <name>root</name>
                <privilege>15</privilege>
                <secret>
                    <encryption>9</encryption>
                    <secret>$9$IRHgr7MCAEFNLk$ZfOrXoRLFhh6gHIxhLPfOC9KzjIWISv4KqkNAR51kmI</secret>
                </secret>
            </username>
        </native>
    </data>
</rpc-reply>
```

Comment: What do you need (which elements) from the `username` element ? How does your output should look like? Please update the post with the required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How annoying are namespaces, right?

This simple [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) expression selects all tags named `username` in any (or no) namespace from anywhere in the entire tree.

```py
users = tree.findall('.//{*}username')
```

Output:

```
[<Element '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}username' at 0x000002352F7529D0>, <Element '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}username' at 0x000002352F751620>, <Element '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}username' at 0x000002352F750CC0>, <Element '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}username' at 0x000002352F751FD0>]
```

It's worth noting that `tree.findall('username')` only finds tags named `username` which are the children of `tree`. It does not search recursively (i.e. the entire tree). In this case, `tree` only has one child, `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156917/python-xml-element-tree-findall-not-returning-anything).

Building on it you could do:

```
namespaces = {
    'Cisco-IOS-XE-native': "http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native"
}
for node in tree.findall(".//Cisco-IOS-XE-native:username", namespaces):
    print(node)
```